# Display records by row number using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

The following code will show the last record in the textboxes. I want to be able to choose which row data to display

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(reader["item_ID"].ToString());
    Item.SubItems.Add(reader["item_Desc"].ToString());
    listView1.Items.Add(item);

    if(action == "add")
    {
        txtitemid.Text = "";
        txtitem.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {   
        //this is the part i am taking about
        txtitemid.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
        txtitemdesc.Text = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
    }
}
```

Suppose the last record in the table has an item_ID of `15` and item_Desc is `dress` then the textboxes will show the following according to code above

```
 txtitemid.Text = 15;
 txtitemdesc.Text = "dress";
```

I want to be able to determine which Item_ID details get displayed in the textboxes

Comment: A relational database like SQL Server doesn't have a concept of "row number" - the data in a table is by definition *not ordered* and no "row number" exists. You'll need to explain in more detail what exactly you're trying to achieve

Comment: @marc_s added more details

Comment: this has nothing to do with the SqlDataReader. This is to do with your query. you can maybe use the ROW_NUMBER function in SQL to return back to you row numbers if you wish. FYI SqlDataReader is just a fast forward only data reader, that's all it does. Alternatively, read the records and construct an object into a collection and then do some logic based upon the collection items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the text box values after your while loop:

```
if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    var displayedItem = listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1];
    txtitemid.Text = displayedItem.SubItems[0].Text;
    txtitemdesc.Text = displayedItem.SubItems[1].Text;
}
else
{
    txtitemid.Text = "";
    txtitemdesc.Text = "";
}
```

**EDIT:**

Similarly, you could display the first item by changing the line in the code above to:

```
var displayedItem = listView1.Items[0];
```

Comment: suppose i want the firstItem instead of lastItem

Comment: @user2650277, I added that to my answer.

Comment: displayedItem.SubItems[0] should be displayedItem.SubItems[0].Text

Answer (score 0):

```
if (reader.Read())
        {
            var readMore = true;
            while (readMore)
            {
                var val = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();

                readMore = reader.Read();
                if (!readMore)
                {
                    //Last record. Use val .
                    txtitemid.Text = val;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Not last record. Process val differently.

                }
            }
        }
```